# Understanding a crude estimate for the number of lattice points inside a ball

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integer-lattices, geometry-of-numbers

I've been reading the appendix (A lattice sum) of [this](https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/CTNTmodularforms.pdf) write up by Keith Conrad and pretty much understand most of the argument but I'm stuck on the following:

Let $S(x)$ denote the number of non-zero lattice points inside the ball $\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^d: ||\mathbf{x}|| \leq \sqrt{x} \}$ Since a $d$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ has volume $C_r r^d$ we have, in this case, that $S(x) \leq B_d (\sqrt{x})^d $ for some constant $B_d$ only dependent on $d$.

However he also says that, it follows from this that there exists positive constants $A_d$ and $B_d$ such that $$A_d (\sqrt{x})^d \leq S(x)\leq B_d (\sqrt{x})^d$$ for large $x$. I understand the upper bound as one cannot have more lattice points than a balls volume obviously but I'm not sure how he established the lower bound. This seems like an important principal that could be applied to other problems so I'd really like to understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: In the $\|x\|_\infty$ norm, ball are Cartesian products of integer intervals, whose cardinality can be calculated readily, hence the lower bound.

Comment: Won't there always be more lattice points in the Cartesian product though? How would it translate to a lower bound?

Comment: There are constants $a_d$ and $b_d$ such that $a_d\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\| \leq b_d \|x\|_\infty.$

Comment: Also, your volumen argument about the cardinality is wrong. Measure and cardinality have little to do with each other.

Comment: Not sure about your last comment. Surely the number of non-zero lattice points in a ball is bounded above by the volume. Could you provide a counter example?

Comment: It is true that $|S(x)| \leq B_d x^{d/2},$ so I cannot provide a counterexample. The argument _is still wrong._

Comment: So how would one go about proving even the upper bound on $S(x)$? Based on your comments it seems my intuition is completely off base here.

Comment: I updated the file you linked to in order to include some more details about those bounds, including possible formulas for $A_d$ and $B_d$ in terms of $d$ when $x$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists two constants $a_d$ and $b_d$ (both positive) such that $a_d\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\| \leq b_d \|x\|_\infty.$ Then $S(r) \subset S_\infty(r/a_d)$ and $S_\infty(r) \subset S(b_d r).$ It is clear (because they are products of integer intervals) that $|S_\infty(r)| = [r]^d.$ The result follows.

Comment: Apologize for the late acceptance. I completely forgot about this. Your answer cleared it up for me though. Thanks.

Comment: The formula $|S_\infty(r)| = [r]^d$ is incorrect, e.g., $|S_\infty(1)| = 3^d$ since there are three integers $n$ satisfying $|n| \leq 1$.  A correct formula is $S_\infty(r) = (2[r]+1)^d$, which is bounded above and below by a constant times $r^d$ when $r \geq 1$.

Comment: @KCd You are right, I don't know what I was thinking. It is zero, and $r$ digits on each side.